# The view is not giving me the expected output, even if the preview is correct

Tags: views, commerce

I am setting up a view for my products and using Commerce Kickstart. Whenever I want to display products in a grid, and I assign more than one product to the row, I get a distorted view.

[image: screenshot]

However, the preview gives the correct view. Can anybody suggest me a way to display this grid view properly?

Comment: how many columns you have selected in grid settings?

Comment: I have given 2 columns in grid settings . Is there a way to decrease the size of grid view?

Comment: with css u can do that

Comment: Ya that must be obvious but i mean from anywhere with in Appearence->Theme Settings ?

Comment: no u cant do it from theme settings

Comment: I ll try it with CSS and then post the results !

Comment: No success yet ! Can anyone suggest a solution ?